# Undefined var with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have this simple code in symfony twig,
I want to put the content of a div in a var with jquery but the var is undefined, when I do console.log (numQuiz) I have undefined.

Any help?

```
<div id="numQuiz" > {{ i }} </div>

<script>

  $('body').on('submit', '.ajax', function (e) {

      var numQuiz=$("#numQuiz").text();    
      console.log(numQuiz); 
  }) ; 

</script>
```

Comment: Your code has a mistake. You are missing the brackets for close the `.on` function.

Comment: i forget them when copied the code but it's not the problem

Comment: If you log only `$("#numQuiz")` did you get undefined?

Comment: no it work i don't get  undefined

Comment: I've tried your code in a simple HTML page (without symfony) and it work. I've put the callback function in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: that's weird thank's for the help anyway

Comment: I've maked a JSFiddle for show you: https://jsfiddle.net/ppzdzvct/1/